# Spring-boot 3 migration. Cannot create query using generic fields and @MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to migrate a working application from Spring Boot 2.5 to 3.0 RC1. If I call repository method, I get an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute with the given name [id] on this ManagedType [com.example.demo.domain.AbstractEntity]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.4.Final.jar:6.1.4.Final]
    ...
```

It seems to me that the error is related to Generic type **<T extends AbstractEntity & WithTranslationKey>**. If I remove **WithTranslationKey** from generic - then error disappears.
Is that a bug in Spring-boot 3? In older version of Spring-boot everything works.

Simplified version of the code:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "USERS")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User extends AbstractEntity implements WithTranslationKey {

    private String name;

    @Override
    public String getTranslationKey() {
        return name;
    }

    @Builder
    User(Long id, String name) {
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```java
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class AbstractTranslationEntity<T extends AbstractEntity & WithTranslationKey> extends AbstractEntity {

    @JoinColumn(name = "CLASSIFIER_ID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private T classifier;

    @Column(name = "LOCALE_CODE", length = 15, nullable = false)
    private String localeCode;

    AbstractTranslationEntity(Long id, T classifier, String localeCode) {
        super(id);
        this.classifier = classifier;
        this.localeCode = localeCode;
    }
}
```

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_TRANSLATION")
public class UserTranslation extends AbstractTranslationEntity<User> {

    private String translation;

    @Builder
    UserTranslation(Long id, User classifier, String localeCode, String translation) {
        super(id, classifier, localeCode);
        this.translation = translation;
    }
}
```

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstractTranslationRepository<C extends AbstractEntity & WithTranslationKey, T extends AbstractTranslationEntity<C>> extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {

    List<T> findTranslationsByClassifierId(Long classifierId);

}

public interface UserTranslationRepository extends AbstractTranslationRepository<User, UserTranslation> {
}
```

The error comes when I call

```
translationRepository.findTranslationsByClassifierId(1L);
```

Comment: Upd: It seems to be a regression in Hibernate 6.1.x, opened an issue : https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15687

Comment: Upd 2: The bug on Hibernate side is fixed.